# How To Grab Output From Other Console Program

Tags: c++, windows, console

I am developing a a program that grabs everything that is sent to the console of another program. I do not have acces to that programs source, I just need to grab its output.

I have no idea how to do this in C++ on windows.

Comment: Look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5531/Redirecting-an-arbitrary-Console-s-Input-Output). Might help...

Comment: Do you have to attach to an external running process, or can your program start the other process? If you're starting the process, look at [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) you can control the process stdin/stdout.